# how to integrate appery.io with Amazon AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, appery.io

Please help me with steps to integrate  Appery.io  with Amazon AWS S3 using REST API?

The mobile app has a feature that uploads photos to AWS S3 and keeps  references of photos in database.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: This is a very vague question. Please refine your question to be more specific. What part of integration doe you need help with? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: How to  create a service that connect Appery.io platform  to Amazon S3 using REST API? This is needed for uploading files to Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect to any external REST API from an Appery.io app: 1) using Server Code; 2) using API Express. This page has more information and examples: https://docs.appery.io/docs/apiintegrations-overview#section-external-rest-apis. Hope this helps.